# explode string if it contains non-alpha characters

Tags: php, arrays

How can I explode a string like `"bla_bla"` into an array like `array('bla', 'bla')`?

The delimited `_` can also be any character besides numbers 0-9 and letters A-Z (both upper and lower case).

Answer (score 7):

Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$input = 'bla_bla$bla';
$items = preg_split('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $input);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/RjO8J).**

Comment: use mb_split for utf-8 support.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$array = preg_split('/[^[:alnum:]]+/', 'bla_bla');
```

Try it here: http://codepad.org/587rsJIU